# Rails: scaling with group calculations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scalability

Currently I am running something similar to this command:

```
Person.sum(:cholesterol, :group => :age)
```

which seems to work great when I have a small number of records. However when I attempt to call this with a few thousand records or more in the table, it takes literally minutes to run. However, the SQL query:

```
SELECT sum(`people`.cholesterol) AS sum_cholesterol, age AS age 
FROM `people` 
GROUP BY age
```

Takes around 0.02 seconds on the same thousand number of records. Once I have the data I don't need to do much more than display it. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I am aware that I can manually make SQL queries from models and controllers, I don't know if this would be a viable option as I have not found a clear way to work with the result once the query is made.

Comment: Well if that's not that SQL query that takes so much time, it must be something else. Look at your log to see if there aren't any other sql queries that might be too long (or too many sql queries).

Comment: Thank you, it is the query that is taking the time. When I run the command in the mysql environment it is pretty much 1000x as fast as when it gets called via rails. Is it really possible that rails is that slow on this method? I am only having issues with this one method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what it's happening is that Rails is instantiating an object per row requested or used on the sum, or keeping in memory information to help that calculation.

Try using the find_by_sql method, something like:

```
Person.find_by_sql("SELECT sum(`people`.cholesterol) AS sum_cholesterol, age AS age FROM `people` GROUP BY age")
```

And see how much it takes.

Also, check your logs. They gave you plenty of information on where is taking so long render.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned previously looking at my logs it is running the expected SQL query "SELECT sum( ..." this is the ONLY thing I see that is occuring when I run the command. 

Your solution is what I was looking for, the run time is pretty much the same as runnning it in a MySQL environment.

I still am unaware why exactly the Rails method takes so much longer when it ends up calling the exact same SQL.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running your app?

Logs can give you great information and with mongrel, in development mode you will see the sql queries being executed by your app directly in the terminal or in your log file if you detached mongrel.

Maybe rails is not doing the query you are expecting?

You can also use the solution suggested by Yaraher.

find_by_sql will directly execute the request an return you a Ruby object with getter methods ready to be used

```
result = person.find_by_sql("SELECT sum(`people`.cholesterol) AS sum_cholesterol, age AS age FROM `people` GROUP BY age")

p result.sum_cholesterol
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
Person.find(:all, :select => "sum(cholestorol) as 'sum_cholesterol'", :group => "age")
```

It may be a bit cleaner, but I don't know if it'll be faster than find by sql.

Comment: This solution also was much faster than Person.sum(:cholesterol, :group => :age)